# How should I prepare drywall for wallpaper?

Tags: drywall, wallpaper

If I am posting wallpaper, is it still necessary to apply joint compound?  I though that corner could be cut because the surface won't be exposed especially if i cut all the beveled edges off and achieve a uniformly thick surface.  i thought that wallpaper adhesive would fill the little holes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should still mud, tape and sand all of the drywall joints especially if your drywall has beveled edges. Ideally you would also apply a coat of primer before you apply the wall paper as this makes removing it easier down the road, and if you do ever decide to paint it, at least all you'll need to do is remove the wall paper and paint and not have to deal with mudding the joints.

Comment: the beveled edges were what i was particularly concerned about.  however, let's assume i cut out the beveled edges so the DW thickness was uniform everywhere.  in that case, would it be feasible to avoid mudding/taping?

Comment: I suppose so, but someone down the road will really dislike you!

Comment: You should also apply a coat of wallpaper seizing over the primer.  I recommend a PVA drywall sealer as a primer followed by the seizing.

Comment: @Steven, that is the least of my worries.  Drywall is easy to replace, if someone down the road wants to have it painted

Comment: @foampile, don't take this the wrong way, but I already dislike you for making others replace drywall because you don't want to properly prep the surface.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mud it, the wallpaper is gonna highlight every screw, seam and flaw. It will have air bubbles over every screw and gap. Would look like a real hack job. Anything worth doing is worth doing well.