# Preparing plywood for wallpaper applications

Tags: adhesive, wallpaper

I have erected false walls using plywood on concrete wall for hiding aquarium piping and electrical wires. I am planning to finish the board using wallpaper.

Can I simply glue up the wallpaper on the bare plywood? Or is it necessary to paint undercoat beforehand?

The wall is partly smooth texture plywood and another part is osb board. The osb board by nature is not as smooth as the plywood.

If I simply use glue and stick the wallpaper on these walls, will it show up some differences?  My main concern is just that.

Please advise me. Thank you.

Comment: I think this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/23286/how-should-i-prepare-drywall-for-wallpaper?rq=1 , even though it's specifically about drywall, still applies.  Any bumps / unevenness you have on the plywood, you'll see on the wallpaper.

Comment: My first thought was to prime the plywood and tape/skim coat with drywall mud to get a totally smooth surface, but I'm not sure how that would work on top of plywood.